# Thymeleaf layout with multiple contents

Tags: layout, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new on Thymeleaf template engine, and I'm making an application with Spring Boot and Spring MVC. I'm working just with `application.properties` for the configuration.

I want to know how I can write only **ONE** layout but the contents in many files: for example `content1.html`, `content2.html`, etc. and use the layout that already have the header, the footer.

If it is possible, how can I send from the controller the content file that will be replaced in the layout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this. Let's say you create a page where all other content will be embedded - `main.html`. It will look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<div th:fragment="mainPage(page, fragment)">
    <h4>Some header</h4>
    <div th:include="${page} :: ${fragment}"></div>
    <h4>Some footer</h4>
</div>
</html>
```

Then you want to create some page which will be embedded in your `main.html` page - `some-page.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<div th:fragment="somePage">
    <h1>${title}</h1>
</div>
</html>
```

The goal is to replace `<div th:include="${page} :: ${fragment}"></div>` within `main.html` with the content from `some-page.html`. In controller, that will look like this:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String somePage(Model model) {
        // Note that you can easy pass parameters to your "somePage" fragment
        model.addAttribute("title", "Woa this works!");
        return "main :: mainPage(page='some-page', fragment='somePage')";
    }
}
```

And there you go! Every time when you want to swap content in `main.html`, you just change `page` and `fragment` parameters within string in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Branislav, but when the action of the controller return something, the container searches for a view having the same name returned! and it will never find something like "main :: ...."

Comment: @MohamedRedaArherbi Did you try it? I tried it and oh yes it will. You can return fragment name expressions from controller method. "main :: mainPage(...)" is definitely legit. It will return `mainPage` fragment from `main.html` file.

Comment: Indeed, there is some progress and it's close to the solution, but the problem with this maneer is that when the controller returns the view it delete all the previous code in the main page (html tag, head tag, all css ...)

Comment: @MohamedRedaArherbi Just include CSS, JS and other tags in `mainPage` fragment. I.e. you can create `header` fragment which will contain all CSS inclusions :)

Comment: Oh Yes it worked now after that I put `th:fragment="mainPage(page, fragment)"` in the tag  `<html ....>`, so I have now `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="mainPage(page, fragment)">`
**But I have just one question**: If I have in my main page other fragments like header and footer, they will be reloaded after each call?

Comment: @BransislavLazic Did you understand my question? if not, I meant if that the whole page will be re-written (even the common fragments) ?

Comment: Depends if it's being cached. But nevertheless, Thymeleaf template engine will ingest page together with included fragments in order to render it. I don't see an issue with that.