# layout view, bootstrap not taken in account - spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot

I have created a layout view which would wrapped different views of my small application. Below is the hierarchy of the project

[image]

The layout view (`template1.html`) is completely ignored when the view `comptes.html` is returned by the controller. The view `comptes.html` should be wrapped in `template1.html`.

**template1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Ma banque</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/myStyle.css"
    th:href="@{/css/myStyle.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a th:href="@{/operation}">Operation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**comptes.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="template1">
<head>
<!-- Thymleaf utilise utf-8 -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>MyBanQ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Consultation d'un compte</div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller

```
@Controller
public class BanqueController {

    @Autowired
    private IBanqueMetier banqueMetier;

    @RequestMapping("/operations")
    public String index()
    {
        return "comptes";
    }
}
```

Moreover Bootstrap styles are completely ignored when I tested separately the layout view `template1.html`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `bootstrap-4` if you aren't using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: I have corrected the tags ;)

Comment: Show your spring-boot controller code as well as the file hierarchy of the project in expanded form.

Comment: I have edited my post ;)

Answer (score 0):

This has not been tested but to take CSS files into account, just use `href` and comment/remove `th:href` for now (later on you can test by uncommenting/adding it back). In `href` you have to modify your path like `css/bootstrap.min.css` and `css/myStyle.css` for both the CSS files.

Now the question

> The view comptes.html should be wrapped in template1.html.

You have to use `th:fragment` and `th:include` of **Thymeleaf** in both the HTML files. The idea is to embed **comptes.html** into **template1.html**. In other words include the **comptes.html** into **template1.html**. You also need to changes logic (in `return` statement) in your controller accordingly. If you are not familiar with the **Thymeleaf Page Layout**, I recommend you to go through [this link](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html).

I found the very [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289723/thymeleaf-layout-with-multiple-contents). I'm providing this link just to help you, and do not wish to take any credit for this.